# Poetry already added module, but not installed

Tags: python, virtual-environment, python-poetry

My `pyproject.toml` is something like this

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
numpy = "^1.19.4"
pandas = "^1.1.5"
matplotlib = "^3.3.3"
seaborn = "^0.11.0"
lightgbm = "^3.1.1"
jupyter = "^1.0.0"
notebook = "^6.1.5"
.
.
.
[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

After `poetry install` and open python, I found I could import some module(numpy and pandas), but not others like seaborn, lightgbm and etc..
Anyone knows how to fix this problem?
I got same situation, so I manually deleted `.venv` and `poetry.lock`. Then I re-added modules by `poetry install`. But it didn't go well...

```
$ poetry run python
Python 3.9.1 (default, Dec 10 2020, 10:36:35)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import numpy
>>> import pandas

>>> import seaborn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn'

>>> import lightgbm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lightgbm'
```

I guess `llvmlite` is a main cause of this problem, so I'll work on looking around for solution. But if you already know about it, please share.

```
$ poetry cache clear pypi --all
$ rm -r .venv
$ rm poetry.lock
$ poetry install

### a lot of process goes on

  • Installing colorama (0.4.4): Installing...
  • Installing llvmlite (0.35.0rc3): Failed
  • Installing llvmlite (0.35.0rc3): Failed
  • Installing colorama (0.4.4)
  • Installing llvmlite (0.35.0rc3): Failed
  RuntimeError
  Unable to find installation candidates for llvmlite (0.35.0rc3)
  at /usr/local/Cellar/poetry/1.1.4/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
       71│         if not links:
    →  72│             raise RuntimeError(
       73│                 "Unable to find installation candidates for {}".format(package)
       74│             )
       75│
       76│         # Get the best link
```

#### Followings are possible clues to solve

poetry replies it is already installed.

```
$ poetry add seaborn
The following packages are already present in the pyproject.toml and will be skipped:

  • seaborn

If you want to update it to the latest compatible version, you can use `poetry update package`.
If you prefer to upgrade it to the latest available version, you can use `poetry add package@latest`.

Nothing to add.
```

```
$ poetry run which python

/Users/<user>/.venv/bin/python
```

```
$ poetry env info

Virtualenv
Python:         3.9.1
Implementation: CPython
Path:           /Users/<user>/.venv
Valid:          True

System
Platform: darwin
OS:       posix
Python:   /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9
```

```
$ poetry -V

Poetry version 1.1.4
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you could narrow it down to a [mre].

Comment: Thanks. There were many problems I faced before this question and I felt distressed. I'm going to identify what's main problem and revise this question later.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this problem. This problem is just about failure of installing `llvmlite`, rather than poetry. `llvmlite` is pre-requisite for installing `pandas-profiling` I was trying to install.

Rule of thumb when it comes to finding dependence problem

1. removing current environment

```
$ poetry cache list
# after finding out what cache exists
$ poetry cache clear <cache name> --all
$ rm -r .venv
$ rm poetry.lock
```

2. Take a note or copy of what modules you have installed

```
$ cat pyproject.toml
# take a note or copy of what modules you have installed

$ rm pyproject.toml
```

3. re-initialize environment and adding modules incrementally

```
$ poetry init
# not adding modules except ones you are sure not to cause problem

$ poetry add <module>
```

4. Identifying what is actually problem

Comment: `poetry show --tree` will show you a dependency tree :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had a super-specific case, but it happened basically because `direnv` tool applied a different `venv` beforehand which mixed up everything.